# Eclipse: Blockwise field alignment with Java Code Formatter

Tags: java, eclipse, alignment, field, formatter

I am using the code formatter and want a special form of alignment for fields.

I am not too happy with the option "align fields in columns". I don't like that all fields are aligned the same way, which can produce a huge number of tabs and does not look good anymore. Especially when you have long declarations like the following in your code:

```
    public static final Uri     CONTENT_URI_ROLLBACK_UPDATE = Uri.parse( "content://"
                                                                    + AUTHORITY
                                                                    + "/"
                                                                    + "ROLLBACK_UPDATE"
                                                                    + "/"
                                                                    + TABLE_NAME );

    String                      ID                  = "id";
```

I would prefer that code is formatted blockwise. Which means: If there is a blank line in between then a new column alignment shall start. Do you know any options to realize that?
 Perfect would be a solution, which can be applied with the code formatter.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this plugin:

http://eduardpblog.blogspot.ch/2012/06/eclipse-plugin-that-aligns-java.html

Select a block of lines and hit ctrl+4, the plugin will align them "correctly".

It’s not integrated in the formatter, but it works in all text files, not only java.